Proving Hölder-Type Inequalities and Existence in $L^p(\mu)$ Spaces.
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $r \geq 1$ and $p, q \in (r, \infty)$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q},
$$
and let $f \in L^p(\mu)$ and $g \in L^q(\mu)$.
(a) Let $p' = p/r$ and $q' = q/r$. Define $F = f^r$ and $G = g^r$. Prove that $F \in L^{p'}(\mu)$ and $G \in L^{q'}(\mu)$.
(b) Prove that $fg \in L^r(\mu)$ and that
$$
\|fg\|_r \leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q.
$$
I believe this is a Hölder-type inequality, but I've only come across the inequality for when p and q are conjugate and would like a full proof or derivation, since unsure if my hunch about this being some sort of extension of the conjugate Hölder inequality is even the right direction.
If possible, please provide some intuition about why these results hold.

This is indeed related to the classical Hölder's inequality, which corresponds to the case $r=1$.
For the first part, use that $\left(\lvert f\rvert^{r}\right)^{p'}=\lvert f\rvert^{rp'}$ and that $rp'=p$.
For the second part, applying the usual Hölders inequality to $F$, $G$ and the conjugate exponents $p'$ and $q'$.
